# SQL Server 2012 - How to extract a value from an XML string?

Tags: sql-server, xml

This seems very basic,  but I haven't been able to find an example that works for me, so I'd appreciate any advice.

I have a SQL Server function that determines various dates based on our fiscal year and today's date, and returns one row which looks like...
`<row LastDayPrevMonth="2015-04-30T00:00:00" LastDayPrevMonthLY="2014-04-30T00:00:00" ...  />`

In the stored proc which calls that function, I've done...

```
DECLARE @X XML
SET @X = dbo.GetFiscalYearDates()
```

...but then I can't seem to extract the value of LastDayPrevMonth.

I've tried dozens of variations of this:
`SELECT ROW.ITEM.VALUE('LastDayPrevMonth', 'VARCHAR(30)')[1] AS Foo FROM @x.nodes('row/item')` ... sometimes with an "AS Bar" at the end...

That particular syntax gives the error "incorrect syntax near the keywork 'as'", but any tweaks I do don't help.

Thanks for your assistance, dudes!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
declare @doc xml

select @doc= '
<root>
<row LastDayPrevMonth="2015-04-30T00:00:00" LastDayPrevMonthLY="2014-04-30T00:00:00" />
</root>
'

SELECT 
      LastDayPrevMonth = Y.i.value('(@LastDayPrevMonth)[1]', 'datetime')
    , LastDayPrevMonthLY = Y.i.value('@LastDayPrevMonthLY[1]', 'datetime') 

FROM 
    @doc.nodes('root/row') AS Y(i)
```

Comment: I appreciate it granadaCoder; I can't vote you up because I don't have 15 points earned.   For future readers, the function which returns the XML has to have the clause on the end:  ... FOR XML RAW, ROOT('root')   to get the root node in there.